# Como criar um arquivo .bat que de o ionic serve?

Tags: ionic, cmd

Boa noite, estou tentando criar um arquivo .bat para rodar o ionic serve, porem não estou tendo bons resultados e preciso de ajuda!
Segue o que eu fiz:

cd C:\Users\ernetwork\Desktop\ERN_ADM\instação\site\projeto 
ionic serve
porem não funciona.

Comment: Não é uma questão de projeto de software, você poderia remover esta tag e evitar buscas desnecessárias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use aspas no caminho

2) adicione no bat:  `cd /d %~pd0`

3) execute a chamada do ionic server ([consulte o comando aqui!](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/))

4) Verifique se as variáveis estão disponíveis e corretas([consulte variáveis aqui](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html#environment-variables))

```
cd "C:\Users\ernetwork\Desktop\ERN_ADM\instação\site\projeto ionic serve"
```